# How to do downsampling in AVFoundation screen capture?

Tags: avfoundation

I use three classes to do screen capture in AVFoundation:

```
AVCaptureSession  *m_captureSession;   // AVCaptureSession
AVCaptureScreenInput  *m_screenInput;      //AVCaptureScreenInput
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput  *m_videoOutput;      // AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
```

And handle the each frame with AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate. I have my own encoding module to process the frame buffer.

But the original Retina Display resolution is too much for my case. So I am wondering if it is possible to do downsampling without any encoding/compression in AVFoundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `m_screenInput.scaleFactor` to something smaller than 1, e.g. 0.25.

The header file gives an example of scaling *up*, but scaling down works too:

> A property indicating the factor by which video buffers captured from the screen are to be scaled.
>   By default, AVCaptureScreenInput captures the video buffers from the display at a scale factor
>       of 1.0 (no scaling).  Set this property to scale the buffers by a given factor.  For instance,
>       a 320x240 capture area with a scaleFactor of 2.0f produces video buffers at 640x480.